# SlimerJS window is not opening instead it is showing message in alertbox

Tags: casperjs, xvfb, slimerjs

We have installed slimerjs,phantomjs,casperjs on VM(we are accessing it through 'putty').When we tried to execute the casperjs test suite by following command:

```
casperjs test --engine=slimerjs 'testsuite name' --username --password
```

we are getting an alert message saying,

> slimerjs is already running,but is not responding.To open new window, you must first close the existing slimerjs process, or restart your system.

Comment: Check if slimer is running with `top` and `kill -9` it if it is. Do you have X in your virtual machine? If not, then you need to use xvfb, because slimerjs is not headless.

Comment: we have installed xvfb but still we are facing the issue.can you tell us how to check process name for slimer?

Comment: `ps -A | grep slimerjs`

Comment: We tried it again it shows only one active slimer process..but still we are getting the popup, does it have to do with Mozila version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with slimerjs version, actually we were installing 0.9.3 so it was throwing alert. Now with 0.9.5Version it is working fine